# CSS Opacity Not Transitioning

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have created a small tooltip test using a `div` with an `input` and `p`. However, when I try and increase the opacity so that the tooltip effectively fades in and out, something seems to go wrong. I've tried this on Firefox & Chrome so far and can't figure out what the problem is.

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/2vsts8fv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the `display: none` property, which applies immediately.

As an alternative, you can use `visibility` to hide your item, which also plays along well with transitions:

```
p.tip {
    display: inline;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1s, visibility 1s;
}
div.tooltip:hover > p.tip {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vsts8fv/1/)

Comment: Thanks Cedric! I've always steered clear of  `visibility` personally as it still takes up space and can be accessed, for that reason I'd always use `display: none` but I think in this instance, `visibility` is probably best! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using `display: none`. Try `visibility: hidden` and give a better position through CSS.